# Android Image Crashes The Application

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I am trying to add an image to my newly created app. But , when I run my app it crashes. I have written no code in my app so I am providing XML code and error log.
I have used ImageViews in my previous applications. No errors were there.
I have optimized my images but still, it is giving me the error.

IMAGE DETAILS

[image]

**ERROR LOG :**

> 09-08 16:03:02.266 15137-15137/com.example.avail.instagramclone
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.example.avail.instagramclone, PID: 15137
>           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.avail.instagramclone/com.example.avail.instagramclone.LoginActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error
>   inflating class ImageView
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class ImageView
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>               at com.example.avail.instagramclone.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:15)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210) 
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097) 
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>            Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060058
>               at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getValue(ResourcesWrapper.java:208)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:328)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
>               at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:58)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:77)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:67)
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:181)
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:105)
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
>               at com.example.avail.instagramclone.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:15) 
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248) 
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210) 
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097) 
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have an image called logo inside your drawable folder? In what folder is it placed? Android isn't able to find some resource to inflate your ImageView, probably is this drawable.

Comment: That's a png image and you are using app:srcCompat which is preferred with vector images use android:src

Comment: I solved my problem! I placed my images in Drawable-v24 folder secondly I used : android: src in the XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your image `drawable` folder if image in `drawable v21 - 2 - 3` so  transfer it in only drawable folder and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:src` instead of `app:srcCompat`

Answer (score 0):

Your log file shows this line

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060058
```

Which indicates that the image file "logo.png" which you refer to in the XML in this line

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
```

isn't in the correct directory. You need to place the file in one of the drawable directories depending on the resolution of the image.

More on this in this topic on the Android Developers website "[Create drawables from resource images](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawables#drawables-from-images)"

Answer (score 0):

use src property instead of `srcCompat` so use

```
android:src="@drawable/logo"
```

instead of

app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"

also add `android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"` to support API version less than 17

Comment: I solved my problem! I placed my images in Drawable-v24 folder secondly I used : android: src in the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

and use

```
 android:src="@drawable/logo"
```

instead

```
 app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
```

Comment: I solved my problem! I placed my images in Drawable-v24 folder secondly I used : android: src in the XML file.

Answer (score -1):

Just replace your image try with another image it will run fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

if you are facing an issue plz let me know

Comment: I solved my problem! I placed my images in Drawable-v24 folder secondly I used : android: src in the XML file.